# How to measure Neo4j indexing speed

Tags: neo4j

I have created a index in Neo4j

```
CREATE INDEX ON :LogEvent(file_id)
```

With this index I am creating 1 million nodes. How do I measure the time for creating/updating index for 1 million records? I tried enabling transaction logs to see the time, but transaction logs are in binary format and not readable.

Answer (score 0):

As of Neo4j 3.4.8 (latest available version) there is no build in way to monitor actual time spent on reads, writes, index lookups, index writes etc. within a transaction.

Your options are

- use EXPLAIN/PROFILE keyword to get idea of the query execution plan and db hits, which roughly correlate to reads/writes. No time though.
- use query log (see dbms.logs.query.* [options](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.4/reference/configuration-settings/#config_dbms.logs.query.enabled), enterprise only) for time spent on whole query
- use 3rd party java profiler, either commercial or open source, beware of all usual issues with profiling java code. Also beware that Neo4j keeps transaction state in memory and writes to disk only at commit.
- create a benchmark that compares node creation time with and without the index (only possible if you don't need the index for lookup, merge etc..)